# Keep track of matches and check against condition

Tags: regex, perl

I have `$entire_line` = `"if varC > 0: varB = varC + 2"`

I would like my regex to find the following: `varC`, `varB`, `varB` in the `$entire_line`

These matches then need to be checked to see whether they exist in a `HashMap`. If so, a `$` should be appended to the match.

Hence the output should be:

`"if $varC > 0: $varB = $varC + 2"`

NOTE: `0` and `2` don't appear in the `HashMap`.

Currently, I have:

```
$entire_line =~ s/(\w+)/\$$1/g if (exists($variable_hash{$1}));
```

However, this does not work as intended as the `$1` in `exists($variable_hash{$1})` does not refer to the previous regex: `$entire_line =~ s/(\w+)/\$$1/g`

Is there a proper way to go about this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your question correctly and you don't need to perform variable value substitution (as in @choroba's answer), but only append `$` character to known variables, and if the `%variables_hash` is not very long, how about concatenating all the keys of `%variables_hash` with a `|` character to get a regex matching all known variables?

```
my %variable_hash = (
        varA => 1,
#       varB => 1, # commented out to check that it will not be replaced
        varC => 1,
);
my $entire_line = "if varC > 0: varB = varC + 2;"; 

my $key_regex = join('|', map { quotemeta $_; } keys %variable_hash);
# $key_regex will contain "varA|varC"

$entire_line =~ s/\b($key_regex)\b/\$$1/g;
# prefix all matching substrings with $ character

print "$entire_line\n";
```

Also check my comment to @choroba's answer.

Comment: Wow, this is a great solution. Definitely had not thought of going about it like this. May I just ask one question.. with the `\b($key_regex)\b` part, how is this replacing the variable correctly when `$key_regex` contains a `string` in the format `varA|varC`? I would have thought it would be trying to match `varA|varC` as a whole and hence find no matches... Thanks for your help.

Comment: `|` in regex has a special meaning of _or_, so it matches if at least one of the substrings separated by `|` matches.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `/e` modifier and put the code into the replacement part:

```
$entire_line =~ s/(\w+)/exists $variable_hash{$1} ? $variable_hash{$1} : $1/ge;
```

Comment: I suppose @Giri wanted to put `$` character before each variable, not replace with a hash value, so the regex would be `s/(\w+)/exists $variable_hash{$1} ? "\$$1" : $1/ge`.

Comment: Thanks choroba! I was not aware of the `/e` modifier.